# Move to Collection command in context menu missing

Tags: interface, workflow, collections

In the latest 3.0 version the Object context menu has changed and the *move to a new collection* is no longer available. Any hints?

This is the old version
[image]

This is the new one.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have switched to *Local View* (as the menu option already indicates). *Local View* is entered by pressing the "divide" key on the numpad <kbd>÷</kbd> which then exclusively shows you only those objects that were selected in the moment you switched. Your *3D Viewport* should also display "Local View" in the top left corner.

The *Remove from Local View* option lets you remove a then selected object from the exclusive view, without exiting out of *Local View*.

To get back the normal *Object Context Menu*, just switch back from *Local View* by pressing <kbd>÷</kbd> again.

*Local View* is for example helpful if you only want to see a single object you're working on without being distracted by other objects in the scene which might get in the view or anything. You only need to select that object and switch to *Local View* instead of changing visibility options for many objects (with the danger of forgetting to change them back afterwards for some objects).

Comment: That was the point. It works now.

Comment: @pippooooo You might consider accepting this answer then.

Comment: @pippooooo Oh, I just saw in your profile you never accept answers :(